# how call a outlook function in outlook htmlbody by clicking on hyperlink in outlook addin application

Tags: vb.net, jquery, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

how to call CreateOutlookContacts function on click on activation link ..

outlook function code is given below

mailItem.HTMLBody = "

Hi,

Welcome in Constacts World....

Please click on below link to add my contact in your address book

**"Activitation Link"**

```
**//my function which i want to call on activation link**

Public Function CreateOutlookContacts(ByVal Sid As Integer) As Boolean

Try 

Dim sql As String = "select * from SubscriberProfile" 

Dim connectionString As String = _ "Data Source=c211\c211;Initial Catalog=Ctc;User ID=sa;Password=sa" 

Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

 sqlconn.Open() ' Sets up the connection, it is closed here
NewContact.FileAs = "arnav chauhan"

NewContact.Email1Address = "arnav.chauhan@gmail.com" 

NewContact.Email2Address = "abc@live.com"

 NewContact.MailingAddress = "Meerut UP, India"

 NewContact.Subject = "Contact crated from vb.net"

 NewContact.JobTitle = "Software Engineer" 

NewContact.Save() 

Next 

end function
```